# Angular injecting ActivatedRoute param to service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-activatedroute

I'm trying to pass string argument from component to a service constructor. In case of static value it was easy:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-board',
      templateUrl: './board.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./board.component.css'],
      providers: [UsersDetailProviderService,
                  {provide: 'boardId', useValue: 'whatever'} ]
    })
```

and at my service:

```js
    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,
                @Inject('boardId') @Optional() public boardId?: string) {
        console.log(boardId);
    }
```

and I got my 'whatever' in the console. 
But what I really wanted to pass, is the real board id. In the component, I'm using activatedRoute to get board id to a local variable.

```js
this.boardId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

How can I pass this id to a service?

@edit I could achieve my goal by calling service method that takes board id as argument, and then initialize service data. But I don't think it's a good way to this?

Comment: You can inject that service into your component and then assign your boardId value to service boardId value


 `this.userDetailsProviderService.boardId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.parmMap.get('id')`

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy : Thats what he dont want to do. Smolovsky : Why dont you think it's a  good way ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek Because then I will need to have an extra method in the service, which do what constructor would, and I will have to assign this id and call this method from a component. Do you think there is no better way to do it?

Comment: @Smokovsky: IMHO, the constructor injection is used to provide some `Dependency Injection` for the `class`.  If you start injecting such setter values using constructor injection, then we should really question the existence of `getter` and `setter` practices. You want to set some value in a class, you create a setter for easier readability and standard practice. Let me give some thought on this question though. Also, lets wait for others to comment on this